# Trouble accessing properties set by JSR223 Sampler in JMeter non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test plan with multiple thread groups, in the first thread group, I'm using the JSR223 Sampler to load properties from a conf.properties file and set them as JMeter properties. And other threads are accessing those properties. This approach works fine in GUI mode, but I'm encountering issues when running the test plan in non-GUI mode. I am using the JMeter version 5.5

Here's the code snippet I'm using as the script in JSR223 Sampler,

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

String propertyFilePath = vars.get("F_PATH");

try {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertyFilePath));

    for (String propertyName : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        String propertyValue = properties.getProperty(propertyName);

        props.put(propertyName, propertyValue);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Error occurred while reading properties: " + ex.getMessage());
    throw ex;
}
```

So in each thread group, I'm trying to use an If Controller to evaluate a condition that depends on the properties set by the JSR223 Sampler. Here's an example of the condition:

`${__P(RPC_ST)} == "123" && ${__P(RPC_ST_ENA)} == true`

The issue is that the condition doesn't seem to evaluate correctly in non-GUI mode. However, in GUI mode, it works as expected.

I have verified the following:

1. The property file is properly loaded, and the properties are set as JMeter properties.
2. The properties are accessible within the same thread group (1st thread group).
3. I set the path to the properties file as a User Defined Variable in JMeter.

I'm wondering if there is any known limitation or specific configuration required to access the properties set by the JSR223 Sampler in one thread group by other thread groups in non-GUI mode. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say anything meaningful without seeing your test plan and/or [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging), most probably it's connected with test elements [execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

I would recommend removing your JSR223 Sampler completely and just passing the path to your `conf.properties` file via [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -q /path/to/conf.properties -n -t /path/to/test.jmx -l /path/to/result.jtl
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked actually removing JSR223 Sampler and using `-q /path/to/conf.properties`, but I was wondering why it is not working and I have to create 2 jmx files for the GUI and non-GUI modes because of this issue.